# Dockerfile CMD gives /bin/sh not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to build this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /root
ENV PATH /root/bin:$PATH

COPY foo ./bin/

RUN test -e /root/bin/foo && echo file exists || echo file missing
RUN foo
```

but the build fails with the error

> /bin/sh: foo: not found

although the line starting with `RUN test -e` outputs `file exists`, indicating that `foo` has been successfully copied to `/root/bin/foo`.

Why `RUN foo` not able to find `foo`?

```
$ docker build -t foo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  48.07MB
Step 1/6 : FROM alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
df9b9388f04a: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:4edbd2beb5f78b1014028f4fbb99f3237d9561100b6881aabbf5acce2c4f9454
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> 0ac33e5f5afa
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> Running in 2a8051ebc3e9
Removing intermediate container 2a8051ebc3e9
 ---> 21b2b4aaccc5
Step 3/6 : ENV PATH /root/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 81eab1ec7d30
Removing intermediate container 81eab1ec7d30
 ---> 658116549586
Step 4/6 : COPY foo ./bin/
 ---> 1ea30752ca5c
Step 5/6 : RUN test -e /root/bin/foo && echo file exists || echo file missing
 ---> Running in a739113a0ef1
file exists
Removing intermediate container a739113a0ef1
 ---> f9d9c0ecc747
Step 6/6 : RUN foo
 ---> Running in 2c8f07185f3c
/bin/sh: foo: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c foo' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Is the file marked as executable?

Comment: Which Docker version are you using?

Comment: @mszalbach docker community 20.10.16

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, it is marked as an executable on the host. Running `chmod +x foo` and rebuilding the Docker file does not solve the error

Comment: If I create a shell script called `foo` and mark it executable and then build your exact Dockerfile, the script is run during the build process. I.e. I can't reproduce your error. What is `foo` on your machine? A script? A binary?

Comment: can u try using     RUN /root/bin/foo

Comment: If `foo` was created on a different architecture (ARM vs. x86 for example), or a different OS (MacOS vs. Linux), or just is missing some shared libraries that aren't present in the base Alpine image, all of these things could cause that "not found" error.  A script with a correct "shebang" line but DOS line endings would also fail in a similar way.

Comment: @HansKilian `foo` is a binary built using Golang

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar `RUN /bin/sh foo` gave a new error `/bin/sh: can't open 'foo': No such file or directory`

Comment: @DavidMaze Good point. Here, `foo` is built on the Docker host machine, which is running Ubuntu 20.04 on a `x86_64` arch

Comment: I think u missed to add root . Can you try with that as well?  RUN /root/bin/foo

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar Tried `RUN /bin/sh /root/bin/foo` and got a new error `/root/bin/foo: line 1: ELF: not found` and `/root/bin/foo: line 3: syntax error: unterminated quoted string`

Comment: It's probably - like David mentions - incompatibility between your build Linux and Alpine. Try changing the base image in your Dockerfile to `ubuntu:20.04` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @HansKilian Using `FROM ubuntu:20.04` works! Now I'm geting a missing dependency error `error while loading shared libraries: libwa.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` but that's beyond the scope of this question

Answer (score -2):

Use this way below:

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /root
ENV PATH /root/bin:$PATH
COPY foo ./bin/
RUN test -e /root/bin/foo && echo file exists || echo file missing
RUN sh /root/bin/foo
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the above will help if `foo` isn't marked executable? OP says, in the comments, that it *is* marked executable.

Comment: His problem is, that it isn't finding the command sh, putting the sh before the command will solve his problem. Another change that I did is the path, I'm using the exact path to execute the file. In your case, I don't remember the error code when we try to execute a file that is not executable. But, you are right when you said that he needs to be sure that foo is a executable binary file.